# Checkbox is not giving Any value after checked in

Tags: php, sql, checkbox

I'm trying to edit my selections using checkbox method, the values which are previously in database are checked while the other's are not. What I'm trying to do is check other checkbox or uncheck the previous selected check box but when i submit my edition nothing got happen because It is not getting values from the checkboxes I don't know why. Here is my Code. Thank you

```
    <?php 
       if(isset($_GET['Institute_Code']))
        {
       $Institute_Code=$_GET['Institute_Code'];
       $getselect=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT radio FROM institute WHERE Institute_Code='$Institute_Code'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($getselect))
{ $Degree_Programs = $row ['radio'];

}}                  
?>
<form action="#" method="post" name="add_Institute">
<div class="container">
 <!--add here-->
          <?php 
                                $char="";
                                $name[]="";
                                $j=0;
                                $dbvalue="";
                    if($Degree_Programs!=NULL )
                    {
                        $Degree_ProgramStrlen=Strlen($Degree_Programs);
                        for ($i=0; $i<=$Degree_ProgramStrlen; $i++)
                    { 
                             $char = substr( $Degree_Programs, $i, 1 );
                        if($char == ',')
                        {
                            //echo $name[$j];
                            //$name="";
                            $j=$j+1;
                            $name[$j]="";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $name[$j] .= $char;
                        }

                    }
                    } 

                    else
                    {} ?>
                <!--" >-->

 <div class="row col-md-offset-1">
          <div class="col-md-9 ">
                <?php echo "<b>Degree Programs</b>"; ?> 
                <br>
                <?php  for($i=0;$i<count($name)-1;$i++) 
                {   if($name[$i]=='Matric Arts')
                    $dbvalue=$name[$i];
                } ?>
                <label>Matric Arts</label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="check_DegreePrograms[]"  value="Matric Arts"  <?php
                $value="Matric Arts";
                echo ( $dbvalue==$value ? 'checked' : '');?>>
                <?php  for($i=0;$i<count($name)-1;$i++) 
                {   if($name[$i]=='Matric Science')
                    $dbvalue=$name[$i];
                } ?>
                <label for="tag_2">Matric Science</label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="check_DegreePrograms[]" id="tag_2" value="Matric Science" <?php
                $value="Matric Science";
                echo ( $dbvalue==$value ? 'checked' : '');?>>
                <?php  for($i=0;$i<count($name)-1;$i++) 
                {   if($name[$i]=='FSc. Pre-Engineering')
                    $dbvalue=$name[$i];
                } ?>
 <label for="tag_3">FSc. Pre-Engineering</label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="check_DegreePrograms[]" id="tag_3" value="FSc. Pre-Engineering" <?php
                $value="FSc. Pre-Engineering";
                echo ( $dbvalue==$value ? 'checked' : '');?>>
                <?php  for($i=0;$i<count($name)-1;$i++) 
                {   if($name[$i]=='Fsc. Pre-Medical')
                    $dbvalue=$name[$i];
                } ?>
                <label for="tag_4">FSc. Pre-Medical</label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="check_DegreePrograms[]" id="tag_4" value="FSc. Pre-Medical"<?php
                $value="FSc. Pre-Medical";
                echo ( $dbvalue==$value ? 'checked' : '');?>>
                <?php  for($i=0;$i<count($name)-1;$i++) 
                {   if($name[$i]=='I.com')
                    $dbvalue=$name[$i];
                } ?>
                </div>
                </div>
 <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right"/>
 </form>
 </div>
 <?php   //} } 

 $pets ="";
 $flag =0;       
 if(isset($_GET['Institute_Code']))
 {
 $Institute_Code=$_GET['Institute_Code'];
 if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//to run PHP script on submit
 if(!empty($_POST['check_DegreePrograms'])){
 // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
 foreach($_POST['check_DegreePrograms'] as $selected){
     $pets .= $selected . ",";
     $flag = 1;

 } 
 }
 }  
 if ($flag == 1) {

    $pets = rtrim($pets);

 }


  $updated =  mysqli_query($con ,"UPDATE institute set  radio='$pets' where Institute_Code=1233");

   if($updated)
 {

 echo "Data successfully updated...";  
 }
 else {
   die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());  
 }

 }
 }
 ?>
 <?php
 include 'footer.php';
 ?>'
```

Comment: `$flag` in your `foreach` loop is currently not assigned any value, you have to check this. Also wrap the part after the closing `</form>` tag with `<?php  ?>`. If possible use PhpFiddle (http://phpfiddle.org/) to show a demo of your current work in progress.

Comment: Thanks but my question is what is going wrong with checkbox I checked the values but when I get them then it shows that it is empty what is wrong with that code

Comment: You don't show in your code where `$dbvalue` comes from. We can't help if you don't show that part.

Comment: Also, you don't show how you update the database.

Comment: Sorry, know I have updated my post in which I'm getting data from DB and saving it in array name string by after separating words. then after this I compare this name array with every checkbox and checked that checkbox on which it got a match which works fine, the problem comes when I check or uncheck the checkbox, it gives me no value, as it has to store the checked value in the DB after checking Checkboxes but it is not working I don't know why......!!